# Etekcity Scroll E1 Wireless USB mouse does not work with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, mouse

I have an Etekcity Scroll E1 Wireless USB Mouse that is not working with Ubuntu(but does work on Windows). According to their website, the mouse is compatible with Linux, and the Amazon reviews for it back up that statement.

When I run

```
grep -i mouse /var/log/dmesg
```

I get the output

```
[    1.003585] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    1.832309] hid-generic 0003:04B4:0033.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.00 Mouse [HID 04b4:0033] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.2/input0
```

Any ideas why it could not be working?

Comment: Same problem with the Etekcity Scroll E6

Comment: What fixed it for me for simply updating the kernel package ( no editing/recompiling the kernel)

Answer (score 1):

I also faced similar issue. I think linux does not have appropriate drivers for this mouse. The issue is related to HID that the mouse is passing is being treated as a keyboard.

There have been similar issues with other mice.

See :

https://askubuntu.com/questions/232564/sharkoon-drakonia-gaming-mouse-doesnt-work-at-all